# Python: Plot multiple distributions on top of each other with y-shift

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I was looking at a research paper and saw this diagram:
[image: Multiple distributions being shown with slight variation in the y so each can be seen.]

I believe I remember seeing a python plot for this - does anyone know a library or plot I can use to create this?

Comment: Maybe you are referring to [this example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html)?

Comment: Yes I am! Thanks for linking.

Comment: Have a look at the JoyPy package, here are some [examples](https://sbebo.github.io/posts/2017/08/01/joypy/)